# Understanding `serializer.save(owner=request.user)`

Tags: django-rest-framework, save, django-serializer

So I am working with DRF `serializers` and I came through `serializer.save(owner=request.user)`.

How I understood this is we can pass some fields to the save and it will be saved in the database with other data received from the request.

But when I passed the fields to the save method, it is still giving the errors for those fields that `these fields are required`

Also the docs show that:

"""Any additional keyword arguments will be included in the validated_data argument when .create() or .update() are called.""""

Please can you explain it.

Comment: You can pass parameters that are *not* required by the serializer. For example here likely the serializer does not contain a field `owner`. The `.save(..)` method will thus use these to set attributes. This is used for example to link the item to a given owner.

Comment: Can you please post an example how to use it.

Comment: @Irfanwani it will be better if you upload your sample code so we can help you.

Comment: @OpticPython i don't understand what you have to do  with my code as it has nothing to do with that. I just wanted to understand its use which i have posted.

Comment: Sure as your wish